# Switching Transient Protection For ADC Pin

Tags: transformer, adc, transient, transient-suppression, switching-transients

I am playing around with one old transformer. I am trying to use it in combination with voltage divider to get AC 230V main into DC range (0-3.3V) suitable for ESP32 ADC input. I build circuit for that purpose. I was able to put voltage into 3.3V range. But I also started to playing around with transient protection for it by using diodes I have currently at hand. However, once I connect transient protection diodes in a circuit I could still catch transients on a oscilloscope (showing screenshots). Can you please help me understand why?

Update:
I try to increase AC component above 3.3V(see 3rd screenshot), just to check if circuit will start cut off peaks. It clearly does at around 3.7V.
But it doesn't work for transients with higher freq?

[image: Schematic]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's to do with your voltage sensing circuit. It's kind of weird how you do what you're trying to do. The line-neutral voltage looks like it can move far away from your circuit GND if things change fast enough that the C1 can't keep up.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to say. I try different circuit with voltage divider on AC side connected by cap to DC voltage divider and having common ground... It didn't help. Problem seems to be related only with high freq transients. I try increase amplitude of AC signal and it is clearly cut at it's peaks. But transients seems to passing. I add additional screenshot

Comment: What is happening when those transients appears?

Comment: Nothing, because it is not yet connected on an analog input of ESP board. I am testing my setup. I am worrying that this could destroy ADC on a ESP board if I would switch on/off transformer from time to time with ESP connected. So I trying to cover this scenario before going further with this, but don't have much experience on this subject...

Comment: What I meant was: What's happening when you see those transients? Are you connecting up something? Are you turning something on or off?

Comment: Transients come from turning on/off transformer from main AC using a switch. I am trying to reuse old soldering station transformer as an AC 230V voltage meter. I am simulating power outage. Worrying what would transients do when I connect above circuit on ESP32 ADC pin for voltage sensing.

Comment: What if you use 1MOhm for R9 (or whatever current limiting resistor for the clamp diode)? I use 100K or more  when connecting to the mains voltage, usually MOhms.